# Why is my link extraction not working?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, concatenation, nonetype

I am looking to learn Beautiful Soup, and trying to extract all links from the page http://www.popsci.com ... but I am getting a syntax error.

This code should work, but it doesn't for any page I try it on. I am trying to find out why exactly it is not working.

Here's my code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url="http://www.popsci.com/"

page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

sci=soup.findAll('a')

for eachsci in sci:
    print eachsci['href']+","+eachsci.string
```

... and here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/3.py", line 12, in <module>
    print eachsci['href']+","+eachsci.string
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
[Finished in 1.3s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `a` element contains no text, `eachsci.string` is `None` - and you can't concatenate `None` with a string using the `+` operator, as you're trying to do.

If you replace `eachsci.string` with `eachsci.text`, that error is solved, because `eachsci.text` contains the empty string `''` when the `a` element is empty, and there's no problem concatenating that with another string.

However, you'll run into another problem when you hit an `a` element with no `href` attribute - when that happens, you'll get a [`KeyError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyError).

You can solve that using [`dict.get()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), which is able to return a default value if a key isn't in a dictionary (the `a` element is pretending to be a dictionary, so this works).

Putting all that together, here's a variation on your `for` loop that works:

```
for eachsci in sci:
    print eachsci.get('href', '[no href found]') + "," + eachsci.text
```